# BLE scan failed for BLE version 4.2 device in react-native-ble-plx

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx

I am developing the smart home app using react native platform. In that, I want to configure my IoT device from a mobile app over Bluetooth.

My device Bluetooth specification is,

> BLE;v4.2 BR/EDR

I am using

> react-native-ble-plx

library in react native for the Bluetooth operations so I am trying to scan the Bluetooth for the connection but my IoT device is not scanned by this library. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you scan your device using a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)? Are you setting the correct [permissions](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx#android-example-setup) for BLE usage on Android?

Comment: BR/EDR (Bluetooth Classic) is a completely different technology from Bluetooth Low Energy. A BLE library won't work with Bluetooth Classic devices.

Comment: Ok, Then what is the meaning of BLE;v4.2?